# How to use the std error from the boot programmatically?

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

In R, I can use the `boot` function (from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/boot/)) to calculate some estimate of a statistic.
How can I read the `std.error` or that estimate into an R variable from the output of the `boot` function?

Take this simple example using the `Boston` data set from the [ISL book](http://faculty.marshall.usc.edu/gareth-james/ISL/)

```
get_mean <- function(data, index) {
  return(mean(data[index]))
}

bootstrap_res <- boot(Boston$medv, get_mean, 1000)
bootstrap_res
```

This prints

```
ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP


Call:
boot(data = Boston$medv, statistic = get_mean, R = 1000)


Bootstrap Statistics :
    original      bias    std. error
t1* 22.53281 0.007650791   0.4106622
```

How can I get the `0.4106622` value into a variable in R code ?

For example I can use

```
mean_original <- bootstrap_res$t0
```

To read `22.53281` into the `mean_original` variable.

How can I read the reported std.error ?
Looking at the other fields in the `boot`'s return, I do not see an obvious way

```
> summary(bootstrap_res)
          Length Class  Mode     
t0           1   -none- numeric  
t         1000   -none- numeric  
R            1   -none- numeric  
data       506   -none- numeric  
seed       626   -none- numeric  
statistic    1   -none- function 
sim          1   -none- character
call         4   -none- call     
stype        1   -none- character
strata     506   -none- numeric  
weights    506   -none- numeric
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply calculate it:

```
bootstrap_res
#Bootstrap Statistics :
#    original       bias    std. error
#t1* 22.53281 -0.008953755    0.399066

sd(bootstrap_res$t)
#[1] 0.399066
```